# Chrome remote debugging port usage for chrome profiling using Webdriverio

Tags: javascript, promise, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, webdriver-io

I am currently using the Chrome profiling APIs to get the code coverage as below.

But whenever I try to run the tests, I get the following **error**:

> **Error: unexpected server response (404)**
>        at ClientRequest.response (/Users/svg7/projects/examples/build/js/testSuites.js:8419:16)
>        at ClientRequest.g (events.js:291:16)
>        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
>        at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:472:21)
>        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
>        at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:361:20)
>        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>        at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)

My **code** is as follows:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import {createSession} from "chrome-debugging-client";

describe("Functional Coverage example", function() {
this.timeout(880000);
it("Get the coverage", () => {
    createSession(async (session) => {
        const api = await session.createAPIClient("localhost", 6813);
        console.dir(api);
        const tabs = await api.listTabs();
        const tab = tabs[0];
        console.log("====>");
        console.log(tab.webSocketDebuggerUrl);
        // browser.stop();
        let client = await session.openDebuggingProtocol("http://localhost:6813");
        await client.send("Profiler.enable");
        await client.send("Page.enable");
        await client.send("Profiler.startPrecisionCoverage", {callCount: true});
        await client.send("Page.navigate", {url: "https://www.microsoft.com"});
        await new Promise((resolve) => client.on("Page.loadEventFired", resolve));
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
        let result = await 
client.send("Profiler.takePrecisionCoverage");
        fs.writeFileSync("coverage.json", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    }). catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
});

    after(() => {
    });
});
```

Steps I am taking:

1. Start the browser via `./chrome --remote-debugging-port=6813`;
2. Run the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the same issue. 
It seems there is one debugger link by tabs, so just replace :

`session.openDebuggingProtocol("http://localhost:6813")`

by

`session.openDebuggingProtocol(tab.webSocketDebuggerUrl);`